# Not being able to see sqlite tables with rubymine data source plugin with osx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, jdbc, sqlite, rubymine

I am attempting to use the data sources pluigin for rubymine 4.0.3 but I am getting an unexpected error.

when I configure the connection and test it, it works fine. However when i connect I am told that there are no tables in the database, even though i can verify that tables are present through the website itself (built test table and added/viewed records)

I have tried both suggested sqlite jdbc drivers but get the same result with both of them. I got this to work on the first try with no problem on a windows 7 rubymine install.

any direction is appriciated.

I didn't get an error message exactly the data source just can't see the tables

Comment: Please provide more details, like the exact error that you get and idea.log: `Help` | `Reveal Log in ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by installing the xerial driver in rubymine drivers directory. Somehow if you manually choose the driver is downloaded elsewhere, and doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: Where do you put the downloaded driver? I have the same problem.

Comment: /Users/[Username]/Library/Preferences/RubyMine[ver]/jdbc-drivers

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, place your JDBC driver(s) in:

- RubyMine 4.x:
    `%USERPROFILE%\.RubyMine40\config\jdbc-drivers`
- RubyMine 5.x:
    `%USERPROFILE%\.RubyMine50\config\jdbc-drivers`